# Jenkins DSL Remove AuthToken

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I would like to remove the authToken on existing jobs.  When we run a provisioner script it created the authToken=secret, now we want to remove it.

This is how it was created:

```
    configure { project ->
        ( project / 'authToken' ).setValue('secret')
    }
```

Removing that code doesn't remove the actual job setting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by removing the Jobs DSL described in the question, but then also following it up by running a script in the console window in Jenkins UI using the following:

```
import hudson.security.*

def h = Hudson.getInstance() 

for (item in h.items) {

  if(item instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob) {

    println item.name + ' ' + item.getClass()

    if(item.name == 'test-job-with-token-equals-secret-defined') {
      def pipeline = org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.class 
      def field = pipeline.getDeclaredField("authToken") 
      field.setAccessible(true) 
      field.set(item, null)
    }
  }
}
```

By running this script, the job confuguration **Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)** was unchecked, which is the end state I was looking for, and so now it should stay this way when initializing all jobs using Jobs DSL described above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem in Jenkins, see [JENKINS-21017](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21017). It has been fixed in Jenkins 2.99.